# In Symfony2, where should I put that function used by my Controller?

Tags: php, symfony, controller

Let's say that a `Human` can have `Item`(s) inside his pocket.  Each `Item` has different effect on the `Human`.

When he use an item, it goes to `ItemController` :

```
class ItemController extends Controller
{
    public function useAction() {
       // Human
        $human = new Human();

       // Item
        $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
        $item_id = $request->request->get('item_id', 0);
        $item = new Item($item_id);

        // Different effects depending on the Item used
        switch($item->getArticleId()) {

            case 1: $this->heal($human, $item, 5); break; // small potion
            case 2: $this->heal($human, $item, 10); break; // medium potion
            case 3: $this->heal($human, $item, 15); break; // big potion

        }

    }

    // The following Heal Function can be placed here ?
    private function heal($human, $item, $life_points) {
        $human->addLife($life_points);
        $item->remove();
        return new Response("You have been healed of $life_points");
    }
}
```

**Does the `heal function` can be placed here ?** I believe that it's not supposed to be in the Controller. But I also believe it should not be placed inside the `Item Entity` (because of the Response, and because it uses $Human)

Comment: Is your code above just an example of what might happen not actual code your using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends. My reasoning for these type of questions is this: if I'll only use the function in the controller, it can stay there. But if it's likely to be a shared function, I'll create a service for it. Maybe you want to be able to heal humans via a command, or a different controller or something. In that case it makes sense to use shared code for this.

[Creating a service](http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/dependency_injection/factories.html) is really easy, and enables you to keep logic in a shared place. In my opinion the controller is more useful to handle the request flow.

Comment: Question not statement, if the function is used a lot in the controller and once or twice in another controller, would it be a bad idea to just instantiate the item controller in the other controller, set the container and call the heal function?  Heal would have to be public of course

Comment: Definitely not, if it's only used in controllers, I would use inheritance, like @smoreno's answer suggests. The way you describe it, you are doing the exact same thing I described, but using the wrong component to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this:

1: Inheritance

```
  class BaseHumanController extend Controller{

  public function heal($param1, $param2, $param3){

  //put logic here

  }

} 

//Extend from BaseHumanController in any controller for call heal() method
class ItemController extend BaseHumanController{

//....
 $this->heal(...)

}
```

2: Create a Class with your heal() method and configure as service as @Peter Kruithof

Answer (score 0):

I absolutly think it would go in the controller.  From Wikipedia:

> the controller mediates input, converting it to commands for the model
>   or view.

If you look at the delete function generated by the symfony2 crud generator it calls remove on the entity:

```
/**
 * Deletes a Bar entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}/delete", name="bar_delete")
 * @Method("post")
 */
public function deleteAction($id)
{
    $form = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    $form->bindRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $entity = $em->getRepository('FooBundle:Bar')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Bar entity.');
        }

        $em->remove($entity);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('bar_index'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason why it should not be in the controller. Just make it a private method, if you are going to use it there only.